# Android MultiPartTextMessages

Tags: android

I'm having trouble receiving `multiPartTextMessages`.
My application divides and then sends messages part by part.
However, whenever a part is coming broadcastreceiver works.
I need to combine this part to get the original message.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

put a special text at the start of every part like `#myTag_msg1_part1`. In broadcast receiver check the special text of every message to know the partno, then accordingly you can join them.

Comment: Thank you so much.Could you provide any sample code?I tried this approach but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(ClassName, "received SMS");

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            // here is what I need, just combine them all  :-)
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            Log.d(ClassName, String.format("message count = %s", messages.length));
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
        }
    }// onReceive()
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer.K_Anas messages don't come in order so I think I would use tags.However,I solved my problem in a really different and good way.No matter how many messages user sents receiver takes just one message.Many many thanks for your time.